# Capybara 'fill_in' Calendar with current date?

Tags: rspec, capybara

Is this possible using Capybara/Rspec?

Right now in my tests im specifically putting a date such as '2016-11-30' for instance for a calendar picker field, but that's not really accurate and it doesn't make sense to constantly update the tests for the "current year" or anything.

Could I use Time.now?

for example

page.fill_in 'Date_Chooser', :with => Time.now.strftime("%y-%m-%d")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, it ended up being `Date.today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`